Maximal torsion-free subgroup of an elliptic curve
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a field $k$. Then we have the subgroup $E_{\text{tors}}$ which denotes all the torsion elements of $E$. This is the biggest subgroup that only contains torsion elements. My question is if we can find also a maximal subgroup that only contains torsion free elements. My first thought was $E\backslash E_{\text{tors}}$, but this is not a subgroup because if $P$ and $Q$ are torsion-free, the is nothing that guarantees me that $P+Q$ is also torsion-free. So we have to eliminate some other points. How does one proceed from here? I am particularly interested in the case $k=\mathbb{C}$

The only time there is a unique "largest" torsionfree subgroup is when that subgroup is trivial or the torsion subgroup is trivial. This is because the torsionfree part is not usually canonically determined. For example, if your subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\oplus (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, then both $\langle (1,0)\rangle$ and $\langle (1,1)\rangle$ are maximal torsionfree subgroups.

(An easier reason why $E\setminus E_{\rm tors}$ is not a subgroup is that it doesn't contain the identity!)

@ArturoMagidin thank you. I would like to find a maximal subgroup of this fashion in the sense that it is not contained in another with the same property. I don't mind if it's not unique

The quotient $E/E_{\rm tors}$ is free abelian (since it is finitely generated and torsionfree). So it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for some $n$. For each generator, find any element of $E$ that maps to that generator. The subgroup generated by those will be a maximal torsionfree subgroup.

@ArturoMagidin I have a hard time believing that the quotient is finitely generated. Think of $E$ as a torus $\mathbb C / \Gamma$. Then the torsion subgroup is dense. But what are generators of the quotient?

You should probably say what fields you're considering (like number fields where Mordell-Weil will give you finite generation, or $\mathbb{C}$ where you're in the case @red_trumpet mentioned).

Actually, if you have $E=\mathbb C/\mathbb Z+i\mathbb Z$, then $E_{\operatorname{tors}}$ consists of all elements with rational coordinates. But then the quotient is still uncountable, meaning it cannot be finitely generated.

@red_trumpet in this case the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$.

@red_trumpet I was thinking Number Field case, yes. For $\mathbb{C}$, the resulting subgroup is divisible and nontrivial, so assuming the Axiom of Choice it is isomorphic to a direct product of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$. I doubt you can give an explicit description in the general case.

Over complex numbers, the torsion subgroup is divisible and hence injective. So, the group splits giving you a maximal torsion free subgroup.

@Mohan this is very insightful. I assume that you mean that $1\rightarrow E_{\text{tors}}\rightarrow E(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow E(\mathbb{C})/E_{\text{tors}}\rightarrow 1$ splits. I can imagine that $E(\mathbb{C})/E_{\text{tors}}$ is torsion-free but it won't be a subgroup of $E(\mathbb{C})$. So where does the torsion-free subgroup appear? Also, how do we know that the torsion group of a complex elliptic curve is divisible? I would accept an answer that contains this information

This is just an expansion of my comment as per OP's comment.
If $A$ is any abelian variety, then the multiplication by a non-zero integer $n$ is surjective. Refer to any book on abelian varieties. So, if one is over an algebraically closed field $k$, then the multiplication map by $n$ is surjective from $A(k)$ to itself. Thus, it is divisible. The rest has nothing to do with geometry.
If $A$ is a divisible abelian group, let $T$ be its torsion subgroup. Then $B=A/T$ is torsion free and being the quotient of a divisible group, $B$ is divisible. Multiplying the sequence $0\to T\to A\to B\to 0$ by $n$ and applying snake lemma, one sees that $T$ is also divisible (You can also prove this directly). Thus the above sequence splits, giving you $A$ is isomorphic to $T\oplus B$.


My question is if we can find also a maximal subgroup that only contains torsion free elements.

Not sure if this counts as "find", but using Zorn's lemma you can prove the existence of such subgroups. Suppose
$$G_1 \subset G_2 \subset \dotsb$$
is an infinite chain of torsion free subgroups. Then
$$G = \bigcup_i G_i$$
is a subgroup, which is torsion free. Because if $g \in G$, then there exists an $i$ such that $g \in G_i$, and as $G_i$ is torsion free, $g$ cannot be torsion. Hence $G$ is torsion free.
By Zorn's lemma, there exist maximal torsion free subgroups.
